# text-indent deformating img in html

Tags: html, css, text-indent

I have a rule to my blog posts that is:

```
p + p {
text-indent: 1.5em;
}
```

defined in a div:

```
.entry-content{
    padding: 2em 3em 4em;
}
```

and I have some pictures inside the `<p>` defined like this:

```
p > img {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em; 
    max-width: 96%; 
    height: auto;
    text-indent: 0em;
}
```

what is happening is that: first the resize of the image happens before it have the indent applied, so the right margin of the picture goes out of the defined padding (3em) the size of the indent (1.5em), shouldn't the image be resized after the indent?

and then even with the `text-indent: 0em;` the image still follows the rule from the p+p and have indentation.

I solved the problem putting the max-width at 96% instead of 100%, but isn't there a more logical way of solving this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max-width` of the image is determined by the width of the `p` that contains the image. `text-indent` does not change the width of the `p`, but it will shift the text/image in, which will cause the image to overhang. Bottom line, you're seeing the correct behavior.

You need to modify your html/css to achieve the desired results. Without a more complete example, I can't offer alternative approaches. You could try `position: absolute` on the image which will cause the image to go to the upper left corner (ignoring `text-indent` and `padding`). If you try this, don't forget to set `position: relative` on the containing `p`.

```
p + p {
    text-indent: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
}

p > img {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em; 
    max-width: 96%; 
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand the concept, thanks.
That piece of code put the image on the right place but it goes under the text like a background image

Comment: @MarcoMartins That's correct, more or less. If you found this helpful, please mark it as the answer.